# Iterating Through DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I was having a hard time with the technical verbiage to word the question, so it might be that it has already been asked, but I am building a DataFrame off my original database and having to manually come in many times to change the value I am pulling off the original. For example:

```
ref_data['Weighted_Note_Win'][0] = df['Note_Weighted'][df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'][df['bid week'] == 14].mean()
ref_data['Weighted_Note_Win'][1] = df['Note_Weighted'][df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'][df['bid week'] == 15].mean()
ref_data['Weighted_Note_Win'][2] = df['Note_Weighted'][df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'][df['bid week'] == 16].mean()
ref_data['Weighted_Note_Win'][3] = df['Note_Weighted'][df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'][df['bid week'] == 17].mean()
ref_data['Weighted_Note_Win'][4] = df['Note_Weighted'][df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'][df['bid week'] == 18].mean()
```

For each, I am having to adjust the row by one and manually reenter that value pull. Is there a one line way to efficiently iterate through that to make it less time consuming?

Thanks!

Comment: it's a good idea to provide a sample data so it's easier for people to help you, can you do that?

Comment: Also note that chained assignment should be avoided.  Have a look at the first red box in the attached link. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Just letting you know that it's very welcome to add questions that are duplicates, but differently worded from questions we already have. If that is the case, we can close it as duplicate with a link to the appropriate question, which will point you and others who might use similar wording to a solution. (Not saying that this is a dupe, I actually don't know.)

Comment: I am not entirely sure of what you are looking for but it seems that you could solve it with a groupby. Something on the lines of `df[df['accepted'] == 'ACCEPTED'].groupby(['bid week'])['Note_Weighted'].mean()`